# Is it possible for a static method to refer to "this" in Java?

Tags: java

I am new to Java. I know `static` is class level and `this` is object level but please let me know if a `static` method can refer to the `this` pointer in java?

Comment: Since what you ask doesn't make sense, I have to ask what it is you are trying to do.  The whole point of a `static` method is that it doesn't have a `this`, so the simplest way to change a static method to have a `this` is to remove the `static` keyword.

Comment: This question addresses the use of static and what it does. It might be useful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413898/what-does-the-static-keyword-do-in-a-class

Comment: You can put an inner class inside a static method and inside that inner class, the `this` pointer would make sense.

Answer (score 4):

No it does not make sense to refer `this` in `static` methods/blocks. `Static` methods can be called without creating an `instance` hence `this` cannot be used to refer `instance` fields.

If you try to put `this` in a `static` method, compiler will throw an error saying

> cannot use this in static context

Comment: @androiddeveloper Which would still not be accessible by `this`

Comment: Without a better explanation from the OP, it would be pointless to speculate on these types of situations.

Answer (score 1):

No, `this` cannot be accessed in a static context. June Ahsan said everything that you probably need to know but I would like to add a little background.

The only difference between an object method and a static method on byte code level is an extra first parameter for object methods. This parameter can be accessed through `this`.
Since this parameter is missing for static methods, there is no `this`.

Example:

```
class MyClass {

    private int b;

    public void myMethod(int a){
        System.out.println(this.b + a);
    }

    public static void myStaticMethod(int a){
        System.out.println(a*a); // no access to b
    }
}
```

on byte code level becomes (roughly speaking, because byte code does not look like this)

```
class MyClass {
    int b;
}

void myMethod(MyClass this, int a){
    System.out.println(this.b + a);
}

static void myStaticMethod(int a){
    System.out.println(a*a); // no access to b
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No but you can create a static object of you class in your class like this
 `private static ClassName instance;` and then you can set it with `instance = this;` in the constructor. this will then be available for you to use in a static method.